# How to analyze the t-SNE(KMeans) result in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, sklearn-pandas, dimensionality-reduction

I have used the t-SNE for KMeans clustering but after getting the [t-SNE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHcuH.png), I couldn't understand how can I relate this with my original data. Can someone please help me to understand the result and what should I do next to better understand the result by making a comparison with my original data?

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,8))
data = df2[['First_Policy_Year','Customer_Age','Educational_Degree','Customer_Monetary_Value','Total_Premium']].values
kmeans_clustering = KMeans( n_clusters = 3 )
idx = kmeans_clustering.fit_predict( data )

#use t-sne
X = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=10).fit_transform( data )

#fig = plt.figure(1)
#plt.clf()

#plot graph
colors = np.array([x for x in 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk'])
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=colors[kmeans_clustering.labels_])
plt.title('K-Means (t-SNE)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Might be helpful! https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Answer (score 1):

This tSNE result looks **random** to me.

Check this [highly voted answer on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264647). The third image shows more structure than yours - and it's shown to be wrong structure...

Don't overinterpret it.  It's probably false anyway.

Improve your preprocessing first. 90% of your work will be data preparation.